# How to loop when using FileSystem.input?

Tags: vb.net, vb6-migration

I'm migrating a program from vb6 to vb.net.
I have a file with multiple lines to read from.

My code:

```
FileOpen(1,FileName,OpenMode.Input)

Do until EOF(1)

   FileSystem.Input( 1 , param1, param2, param3)

Loop
```

My problem with this code is that the loop isn't "looping"...
Its reading the same line over and over.

When using :

```
Do until FileSystem.EOF(1)

    strData = Filesystem.LineInput(1)

Loop
```

The loop works fine.
But I can't use it because I have different params for each line, which is inconsistent.

What is the problem? Why isn't it looping for the first time?
Are there other approaches for tackling this problem?

Answer (score 0):

> Are there other approaches for this kind of code?

Read all the lines of a text file into an array all in memory in one go (assuming it's a text file because you said "multiple lines"):

```
Dim arr = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("path here")
'loop over the array
For Each line as String in arr
  '... process the line
Next line
```

To read a file incrementally, line by line, if it's huge and you don't want to load it all into memory, use ReadLines instead of ReadAllLines:

```
For Each line as String in System.IO.File.ReadLines("path here")
  '... process the line
Next line
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. The problem is that the line is multiple params separated by comma. It can be 2 params or 1 or 3 etc. For example: a,1,2 or a, ,3. I need to assign each param to a variable. How to do it when its inconsistent?

Comment: That's the "process line" part. You can use e.g. `Dim bits = line.Split(","c)` to split the line into bits on comma, and then you have your pieces of the line, and you can assign them to variables, like `Dim name = bits(0)` `Dim age = bits(1)`. If you want to know how many you got, that's `bits.Length` - two commas will result in a `bits` array that has a `Length` of 3

Comment: `ReadLines` should be the default choice and you should only use `ReadAllLines` if it provides genuine value, e.g. if you need random access to the lines or you need to enumerate the lines multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Another example:

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim line As String
        Dim values() As String
        Dim FileName As String = "c:\someFile.txt"
        Using sr As New StreamReader(FileName)
            While Not sr.EndOfStream
                line = sr.ReadLine()
                values = line.Split(",")

            End While
        End Using
    End Sub

End Class
```

If you show us some sample lines from your file we could give more detailed answers.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  For example: param1,param3 or param1,param2,param3 or param1, , param3

Comment: In my code, `values` will be an [Array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/arrays/) where each index will be a field after splitting on comma.  You can check the Length and assign values to different variables based on the index.

Comment: While what you have is not wrong, it would be better to use `For Each line In File.ReadLines(FileName)`. That reduces three lines of your code (`Using`, `While` and `ReadLine`) to one.

Comment: *"assign values to different variables based on the index"*. It's hard to say for sure but I suspect that there's not even nay need to do that. Just use the array elements directly without the variables, unless they are genuinely needed.

Comment: @jmcilhinney True.  I was just showing a different way to process files since Caius Jard
 already used `ReadAllLines()` and `ReadLines()`.  The person is coming from VB6 so they might not be aware of different approaches.  Definitely not sure what they're doing yet, so I didn't get to specific with the code.  If the same variables get re-used for each line then it doesn't make sense.  Maybe they have specific values from certain lines that need to get stored in variables.  Who knows at this point...